# Entity Framework multiple edmx errors

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a data model `AccordEHR` in which I have multiple tables. I could easily retrieve data using one data model. I used another data model named `PayCare` which also has multiple tables.

Now the problem is, in `PayCare`, there are tables which have name exactly that as in `AccordEHR` table. There are similar named tables in both data models. When I created the second data model `PayCare`, the first data model automatically replaces its table with second data model tables which has common name.

Note that tables have similar names but the data differs.

I tried to explain it as simple as I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your models into different namespaces by separating them with folders

```
...
  Database
      PayCare
          PayCareEntityModel.edmx
          ...
      AccordEHR
          AccordEHR.edmx
          ...
```

The `CommonTable` class for both models are then separated into `Database.PayCare.CommonTable` and `Database.AccordEHR.CommonTable`

Comment: Can you explain me what common table class is?

Comment: Also i got  metadata exception when i separated them by folders and different namespaces.

Comment: Ok i got it. After  separating both edmx by folders the connection string changed in app.config. So all i did is replaced my connection string in web.config with the connection string in app.config. Thank you so much.